# This conditional statement is evaluated as true (by the program Tarski's world) however it seems false could you help detect my mistake?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

[image: Tarsk's world]

So the way I read the statement is: there is an object x such that if it's a cube then it is between a and b. However, there is a cube but it is not between a and b, making the statement false. The exercise this came from started with "Common mistakes" so I'm assuming my assertion that this should be false is a common mistake.

Comment: What happens if you suppose $x$ is the dodecahedron in between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: ** if it's a cube, then ...** but if it is not, then ..

Comment: Vacuous truth strikes again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the way I read the statement is: there is an object x such that if it's a cube then it is between a and b. However, there is a cube but it is not between a and b, making the statement false.

It does not say "There is a cube between `a` and `b`".

It says "There is something that is between `a` and `b` *if* that object is a cube."  Objects that are *not cubes* may satisfy this.

---

Recall implication equivalence.
So $\exists x~(\operatorname{Cube}(x)\to\operatorname{Between}(x,a,b))$ is equivalent to: $$\exists x~(\lnot\operatorname{Cube}(x)\vee\operatorname{Between}(x,a,b))$$

"There is something that is not a cube *or* is between `a` and `b`".

Any of the three dodecahedrons will serve as a witness that this is true.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is indeed true.

To see this, we let $x$ be the dodecahedron which is between $a$ and $b$. Because $x$ is not a cube, it is trivially true that $cube(x) \to Between(x, a, b)$.

Comment: That makes sense. So then Cube(Dodec) Is a statement that I can make? Would I translate it as the dodecahedron is a cube? But it will then be false since this is not possible

Comment: You can indeed form the statement $cube(x)$, which is the assertion that $x$ is a cube. If $x$ is in fact a dodecahedron and not a cube, then $cube(x)$ will be false.

Comment: @exodus You **want** $cube(x)$ to be false. As soon as you have found something that is not a cube you have solved the problem. It doesn’t even matter whether the not-cube is between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @exodus Alternatively, any $x$ such that $Between(x,a,b)$ is true will make the entire statement true.